# Dynamic OrderBy() using property not in DB throws exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<Membership> Membership { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered
    {
        get { return !String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName); }
    }
}

public class Membership
{
    public string MembershipId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

In my repository for the `Membership` entity, I'm attempting to order my collection by doing the following where `entries` is an `IQueryable<Membership>` and `orderBy` is a LamdaExpression equal to `{ x => x.User.IsRegistered }`:

```
ordered = Queryable.OrderBy(ordered, orderBy);
```

When I attempt this, I get the following error:

> The specified type member 'IsRegistered' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

How can I order my collection by a property that is not in the database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since IsRegistered is a client side function, then you need to do the ordering using LINQ over objects.  You can convert your LINQ over SQL to LINQ over objects by causing it to get enumerated.  Then once it's a LINQ over objects, you can then order it using LINQ over obect's OrderBy.  A common method of doing that is by calling ToList, like:

```
ordered = Queryable.ToList().OrderBy(ordered, orderBy);
```

If you want to do the ordering on the database, then you need to convert your clientside code to one that is compatible to SQL, like:

```
ordered = Queryable.OrderBy(ordered, (x=>x.User.UserName!=null && x.User.UserName!=''));
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Now I have a more fundamental understanding of Queryable objects.  Thanks!  In my case, it actually made most sense to create `IsRegistered` in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can always sort locally. If you want a calculated property to be used for server side ordering you'd need an expression that your LINQ provider (EF) can translate (into SQL in your case).

For your `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName)` you could use `m=>String.Empty!=(m.User.UserName??String.Empty)` which works for LINQ2SQL. When checking the generated SQL you should get something like

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ''
-- EndRegion
SELECT --fields
FROM [Membership] as [t0]
JOIN User AS [t1] 
ON -- id
WHERE -- your predicate
ORDER BY 
(CASE 
    WHEN @p0 <> (COALESCE([t1].[UserName],@p1)) THEN 1
    WHEN NOT (@p0 <> (COALESCE([t1].[UserName],@p1))) THEN 0
    ELSE NULL
END)
```

I guess EF also translates that likewise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Entity framework's order by is mapped to db fields because it's calling "ORDER BY" clause on SQL side.

If you really want to order your records by a non-db field (however, as far as I can see, you can just order your records by UserName in this situation), you should filter your records, call ToList() and OrderBy on that (obviusly this only order your records after the result returned from the database server).